# An identity between summations involving a binomial expansion.

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Could someone give me some hint to prove that this equality is an identity?

[image]

It's not about homowork; it has arisen in a development and what I want is to go from RHS to the LHS, since the LHS is the most convenient way for the purposes for which I have developed it.

I have verified that it holds for some particular cases and I am sure that it is true in general, but I want to justify it formally. I have not deduced the LHS algebraically, but by observing particular cases.

**<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< EDIT 1 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>**

Below I show the check for *m = 4*.

[image: Polynomial generate by the LHS formula. Distribution by columns]

[image: Polynomial generate by the LHS formula. Distribution by diagonals.]

It can be seen that the same results are obtained (identical polynomials are generated).

What varies is the way the coefficients of each power of *x* are distributed. In the LHS case, these are distributed by columns, while in the RHS case they are distributed diagonally.

With the change *m - n = j* (suggested by Jean Marie) it is possible to match the subscripts of the deltas and the form of the binomial coefficients (combinatorial numbers), but new discrepancies are introduced (the exponents of -1 don't match and the powers of *x* are restricted to even exponents).

Comment: Please recall your definition of $\Delta_p x^q$.

Comment: Oh, sure; simply, with the change m-n=j and applying the combinatorial identity (m-j, m-n) = (m-j, n-j). I was already a bit confused by this. Thank you very much, Jean-Marie. Best regards.

Comment: But With your indication, the change in the subindex of the Delta is achieved, as well as the identification of the combinatorial numbers; but I think something else needs to be done because with that change you only get even powers of x, and the (-1)^p that controls the sign may not assign the signs correctly. I'll need more time to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show the following identity is valid
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^m}&\color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n+j}\binom{m-j}{n-j}\Delta_jx^n
=\sum_{n=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}\Delta_{m-n}x^{m+j-n}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We start with the left-hand side of (1). We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^m}&\color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n+j}\binom{m-j}{n-j}\Delta_jx^n}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{n=j}^{m}(-1)^{n+j}\binom{m-j}{n-j}\Delta_jx^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{n=0}^{m-j}(-1)^n\binom{m-j}{n}\Delta_jx^{n+j}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{n=0}^j(-1)^n\binom{j}{n}\Delta_{m-j}x^{m+n-j}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}\Delta_{m-n}x^{m+j-n}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we exchange inner and outer sum.
- In (3) we shift the index of the inner sum to start with $j=0$.
- In (4) we change the order of summation of the outer sum $j\to m-j$.
- In (5) we exchange variables $n\longleftrightarrow j$.

Comment: There is another way to solve it (https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-show-that-displaystyle-sum_-n-0-m-sum_-j-0-n-1-n-j-binom- m-j-n-j-Delta_j-x-n-sum_-n-0-m-sum_-j-0-n-1-j-binom-n-j-Delta_-m-n-x-m-j-n), which consists in renaming the summation indices of the sums on the LHS (j --> i, n --> k) and establishing the following changes of variables: k = m + j - n, i = m - n. Renaming them back we get the LHS from the RHS. But you solution is a very elegant variant since indices are not renamed or variable changes are made, acting only on the order of the sums and the order of the summation indices.

Comment: Thenk you very much, epi163sqrt, for your solution. There is another way to solve it (https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-show-that-displaystyle-sum_-n-0-m-sum_-j-0-n-1-n-j-binom- m-j-n-j-Delta_j-x-n-sum_-n-0-m-sum_-j-0-n-1-j-binom-n-j-Delta_-m-n-x-m-j-n), which consists in renaming the summation indices of the sums in LHS and establishing the following changes of variables: But you solution is a very elegant variant since indices are not renamed or variable changes are made, acting only on the order of the sums and the order of the summation indices.

Comment: @JesúsÁlvarezLobo: You're welcome. Good to see the answer is useful. :-) Regrettably the link to quora.com is not valid. A comparison with the answer would be nice.